Calculating probability of offspring having dominant phenotype given a random mating - Mendel's First Law
I'm a beginner to python and have been working through the Rosalind problems. If you're unfamiliar with Rosalind, they're a website where you can practice bioinformatic coding through problem solving.
Anyway, the challenge was to take three integers (k, m, n) which represent the number of homozygous dominant(k), heterozygous(m), and homozygous recessive(n) individuals in a population and then compute the probability of a random mating creating an offspring with a dominant phenotype.
I wrote code and solved the problem, but I'm looking for feedback on how it could possibly be simplified or cleaned up. I wrote out a whole probability tree to get my equations and everything, but I just want to know if there is a much simpler way of doing it. I have a tendency of making things much more complicated than they need to be.
#Number of organisms who are homo_dominant (k), hetero (m), and homo_recessive (n)
k = 18
m = 27
n = 20
t = k + m + n

#Probabilities of first selection
Pk, Pm, Pn = k/t, m/t, n/t

#A few variables I made to clean up my equations
t1 = t - 1
k1 = k -1
m1 = m - 1
n1 = n - 1

#Dictionary where the keys are probabilities of first selection and second selection, so "Pktk" /
#means selecting a k and then another k.
variables_dict = {
    "Pktk" : Pk * k1/t1,
    "Pktm" : Pk * m/t1,
    "Pktn" : Pk * n/t1,
    "Pmtk" : Pm * k/t1,
    "Pmtm" : Pm * m1/t1,
    "Pmtn" : Pm * n/t1,
    "Pntk" : Pn * k/t1,
    "Pntm" : Pn * m/t1,
    "Pntn" : Pn * n1/t1,
}

#I made this for loop to modify the values in the previous dict. to update the probability /
#of two organisms producing an offspring with the dominant phenotype
for variable in variables_dict:
    if variable.count("n") == 1 and variable.count("m") == 1:
        variables_dict[variable] = variables_dict[variable] * 0.5
        continue
    if variable.count("m") == 2:
        variables_dict[variable] = variables_dict[variable] * 0.75
        continue
    if variable.count("n") == 2:
        variables_dict[variable] = variables_dict[variable] * 0
        continue
    else:
        continue

#This takes the dictionary and adds up the values to find the total probability
def find_P_dominantphenotype(dict):
    probabilities = list(dict.values())
    result = sum(probabilities)
    return result

probability = (find_P_dominantphenotype(variables_dict))
print(probability)


Why k organisms do not mate?

@vnp I assume you’re talking about how in the for loop there is no mention of k? If so, that’s because any mating that contains at least one individual who is homozygous dominant (k) will result in 100% of offspring having a dominant phenotype. If they were in there, they would’ve just been multiplied by 1, since the probability is 1.

Efficiency
You can simplify the code inside the for loop.  There is no need for
3 separate if statements; you can use a single if/elif construct
instead.  This better conveys the intent of the code and also makes it
more efficient since it performs fewer checks.
Writing it as follows also makes the continue lines unnecessary:
for variable in variables_dict:
    if variable.count("n") == 1 and variable.count("m") == 1:
        variables_dict[variable] = variables_dict[variable] * 0.5
    elif variable.count("m") == 2:
        variables_dict[variable] = variables_dict[variable] * 0.75
    elif variable.count("n") == 2:
        variables_dict[variable] = variables_dict[variable] * 0

The assignments can be further simplified by using the *= operators:
for variable in variables_dict:
    if variable.count("n") == 1 and variable.count("m") == 1:
        variables_dict[variable] *= 0.5
    elif variable.count("m") == 2:
        variables_dict[variable] *= 0.75
    elif variable.count("n") == 2:
        variables_dict[variable] = 0

And the last line is a simple assignment to 0 (no multiplication needed).
Layout
It is customary to place functions at the top of the code, before the
main code is executed.
Documentation
You should add a docstring to the top of the code to describe its
purpose and its output:
"""
Take three integers (k, m, n) which represent the number of homozygous
dominant(k), heterozygous(m), and homozygous recessive(n) individuals in a
population and then compute the probability of a random mating creating an
offspring with a dominant phenotype.
"""

Input
I realize this was a programming challenge exercise, but it would be good to
add code to take input for the 3 variables from the command line, from
a file, etc.
Naming
The names you gave to the variables are good in general.
Unless the variable named t has some special meaning to your equations,
it would be better named as total.
The PEP 8 style guide recommends you use snake_case
for function names, such as:
find_p_dominant_phenotype

Comments
Most of the comments are nicely descriptive and well-placed.  The style guide
recommends docstrings for functions.
The following comment could be removed since it is really not necessary:
#A few variables I made to clean up my equations


This is exactly what I was looking for. You are the bees knees. Thank you a ton for taking the time to look at it and write up this review.

The existing answer is great w.r.t. the code style and compactness. I'll try to present a higher-level overview of what I notice here.
First of all, it's awesome that your code works. It's even better than I can understand it after reading it twice.
However, you're still approaching the problem manually. We often script things to avoid boring long enumerations of something. First of all, let's try to avoid repeated manual computations and code this as a couple of functions:
def _get_mating_prob(first, second, counts):
    total_count = sum(counts.values())
    first_choice_prob = counts[first] / total_count
    second_choice_prob = (counts[second] - (first == second)) / (total_count - 1)
    return first_choice_prob * second_choice_prob

def _get_dominant_offspring_prob(first, second):
    non_full_probs = {
        'nn': 0,
        'nm': 0.5,
        'mn': 0.5,
        'mm': 0.75,
    }
    # All other contain "k" and always produce dominant offspring
    return non_full_probs.get(first + second, 1)

How does it help? Now your final function can get rid of that dictionary entirely and loop instead:
import itertools

def get_total_dominant_offspring_prob(k: int, m: int, n: int) -> float:
    """Calculate the probability of an offspring with dominant phenotype.

    Args:
        k: Amount of dominant homozygous individuals in population
        m: Amount of heterozygous individuals in population
        n: Amount of recessive homozygous individuals in population
    """
    counts = {'k': k, 'm': m, 'n': n}
    return sum(
        _get_mating_prob(a, b, counts) * _get_dominant_offspring_prob(a, b)
        for a, b in itertools.product('kmn', repeat=2)
    )

Note that this function, unlike previous two, is "public", so we should provide documentation for it. I also added type hints, but only as form of documentation: I won't recommend annotating private helpers and running mypy here. Type hints begin to pay off when your code grows, and this script is small enough to not warrant such tooling.
This marginally reduces your chance to make a typo constructing the dict manually - now you don't have 9 cases to verify, but only need to check the function once. Ignoring variables input, with hardcoded values you can simply call it like this:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_total_dominant_offspring_prob(k=18, m=27, n=20))

As a free bonus, now you can test this code a level lower than "produces correct output for given input": it's now possible to write unit tests for every component (_get_mating_prob and _get_dominant_offspring_prob) to ensure that both work as intended.
Please note that I don't try to present a "best" solution (even subjectively). and neither I'm claiming that code above represents a production-grade solution. This is only the first step towards making it more maintainable. To refine it further, I'd consider the following steps:

Write the unit tests
Support input parsing (at least reading k, m, n from stdin and/or CLI arguments - see input function and argparse module, resp.)
Get rid of literal "k", "m", "n" labels - an enum.StrEnum is more friendly to autocomplete and type checkers

